# simple LINQ query

Tags: asp.net-3.5

i am having trouble joinging tables on a LINQ query.

[image]
<sub>(source: [kalleload.net](http://www.kalleload.net/uploads/qiscjknuhutn.jpg))</sub>

As you can see there are three tables there. On my webpage, i want to display the following data in a List View.

betid | bet.title | bet.description | match.location | match.begindate/enddate | teamone NAME | teamtwo Name.

so let me explain this. 
I want 3 fields from the bets table.
I want 2 fields from the match table (where the match.matchid = bet.matchid)
I want 2 fields from the TEAM table (where match.teamone = team.teamid and match.teamtwo = team.teamid)

i hope this makes sense.

thankyou

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you already have the relationships defined.  If you are using the designer, you should have existing entities in the generated classes.

```
var result = bet.Select( b => new {
                 BetID = b.betid,
                 Title = b.title, 
                 Description = b.description,
                 BeginDate = b.match.begindate, 
                 EndDate = b.match.enddate, 
                 TeamOneName = b.match.team_1.teamname, 
                 TeamTwoName = b.match.team_2.teamname 
              } );
```

Note that I'm only guessing at the association names.  You should be able to figure out the names given to them by the designer.

Answer (score 2):

The key to this one is to include a self join on the team table, for team one and team two, like this:

```
var result = from bet in db.bet  
  join match in db.match on bet.matchid equals match.matchid
  join team1 in db.team on match.teamone equals team1.teamid 
  join team2 in db.team on match.teamtwo equals team2.teamid
  select new {bet.betid, bet.title, bet.description, match.location, match.begindate,   match.enddate, team1.name, team2.name};
```